# DiscordJS v14: apply command to more than one user

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been programming a bot that manages points. I have a command with subcommands that allow to either add or remove users' points.
The question that I've not been able to solve is whether I can add/remove the points to many users with 1 command.

Example: I want to remove 25 points to 5 users. Instead of having to call the same command 5 times, I'd like to just do it one time.

Here is the code for this command:

```
const {
  SlashCommandBuilder,
  EmbedBuilder,
  PermissionFlagsBits,
} = require("discord.js");
const { User } = require("../../schemas/user");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("points")
    .setDescription("Manage users' points.")
    .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.ManageMessages)
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("add")
        .setDescription("Adds points to the user.")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("user")
            .setDescription("User to whom the points should be added.")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addNumberOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("value")
            .setDescription("Value to be added.")
            .setRequired(true)
            .setMinValue(1)
        )
    )
    .addSubcommand((subcommand) =>
      subcommand
        .setName("remove")
        .setDescription("Removes points to the user.")
        .addUserOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("user")
            .setDescription("User to whom the points should be removed.")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
        .addNumberOption((option) =>
          option
            .setName("value")
            .setDescription("Value to be removed.")
            .setRequired(true)
        )
    ),

  async execute(interaction) {
    const user = interaction.options.getUser("user");
    const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    const nickname = member.nickname;
    const value = interaction.options.getNumber("value");
    (userData =
      (await User.findOne({ id: user.id })) || new User({ id: user.id })),
      (embed = new EmbedBuilder().setColor("Random"));
    if (nickname) {
      userData.name = nickname;
    } else {
      userData.name = user.tag;
    }
    if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "add") {
      userData.pointsA += value;
      userData.pointsB += value;
      userData.pointsMonth += value;
      userData.save();
      return interaction.reply({
        embeds: [
          embed.setDescription(` You added \` ${value}\` Points to ${user}.`),
        ],
      });
    } else if (interaction.options.getSubcommand() === "remove") {
      userData.pointsA -= value;
      userData.save();

      return interaction.reply({
        embeds: [
          embed.setDescription(
            ` You removed \` ${value}\` Points to ${user}.`
          ),
        ],
      });
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either add 5 user options (require only one of them, so you can also only give the points to one user if you want) like `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, `user4` and `user5` and define them like that in the execution aswell.
Or you make the `user` option a string and you can enter the userIds, tags, or usernames seperated by commas and then make an array out of the users like this (i chose userIds):

```js
const users = interaction.options.getString('user').split(',');

users.forEach(resolvable => {
    const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(resolvable) || interaction.guild.members.cache.get(resolvable.slice(2, -1)) || interaction.guild.members.cache.get(resolvable.slice(3, -1);
    if(!member) return;
    
    // and then execute all the code you want to execute per user...
}
```

And btw you don't have to get the `GuildMember` like this:

```js
const member = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
```

You can get it like the `User`:

```js
const member = interaction.options.getMember('<your user option name>');
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply! 
The member in forEach is undefined.

Comment: that means, you provided an invalid userid

Comment: It's probably because the forEach provides the IDs with the "<@...>" and not only the numbers. Therefore, I have to find a way to remove that.

Comment: yea but I said you should only enter the ID, but I edited it so you can enter the id **or** ping the user